# how to enable Grafana

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I have already **Grafite running** on my local machibe. I can access it at `http://localhost:8080/`

I tried to configure also Graphana but something is not correct because when I access it via web-browser it tries to access and then fails with error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> mygrafana.com’s server DNS address could not be found. Search Google
>   for grafana 8080 ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

This what I did so far regarding grafana:

**/etc/grafana/grafana.ini**

```
[database]
type = postgres
host = 127.0.0.1:5432
name = grafana
user = graphite
password = mypass

[server]
protocol = http
http_addr = 127.0.0.1
http_port = 3000
domain = mygrafana.com
enforce_domain = true
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s/

[security]
admin_user = admin
admin_password = mypass
secret_key = something

...
...
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/apache2-grafana.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ServerName mygrafana.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also run other commands like to Enable proxy modules `sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http xml2enc`

Enabled Grafana:

```
sudo a2ensite apache2-grafana
```

Configured Grafana to run after boot and then start service:

```
sudo update-rc.d grafana-server defaults 95 10
sudo service grafana-server start
```

and restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Although this is not working, when I enter the address `mygrafana.com:8080` (also tried port 80) it does not work!

Comment: Can you access `http://localhost`?

Comment: It redirects to mygraphana.com. It might be an issue here